# How to deal with fabric colors? Studio strobe lighting

Tags: white-balance, product-photography, studio-lighting, color-correction, strobes

i've problem with colors. On the right is fabric with WB set with X-rite Color Checker Passport, and the camera profile is also made with Passport.

On the left is this same photo but after more adjustments.

Fabric on the left looks like it looks on daylight, but a hand, buttons and x-rite is too green. On the right side image x-rite, buttons and hand looks good, but the fabric isn't like it looks like on the daylight.

What am i missing? How to correct that without doing it manually (checking by eye the screen and the dress) one dress after another.

It was shot in studio, with Canon 5D, Canon 100 mm L, and Bowens Gemini Pro strobes.

I will be grateful for all the advice.

Simon.

[image: Dresses with X-rite Color Checker]

Comment: Stupid question: what monitor do you have? A Adobe RGB monitor will be able to display the greens way better. Just because you dont see them correctly on the screen, does not mean that they are not correct digitally. Is you monitor calibrated?

Comment: Any idea what color temperature the strobes produce? It might considerably different from daylight.

Comment: @sharkyenergy

If what you say is true, then why on the left photo i see the fabric green as it should looks like? 

And yes, i have calibrated Eizo monitor.

Comment: @D. Jurcau 

Ofcourse strobes have different color temperature but it doesn't matter if its CRI is almost 100% as daylight.

Comment: Textile dyes are notorious for metameric mismatch (and green is about the worst colour that you can pick). Even the best studio lighting won't circumvent that. You could repeat the test in full daylight, but be prepared for a lot of tweaking in Photoshop. Using LAB colour-space for adjustments can be helpful, but you will need to read-up on how to use it first. +1 for using colour profiling.

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered that we remain unable to make a faithful image. If we could, you would need to don sunglasses at the cinema when viewing a sunlit vista. The camera relies on the physics that we can image in three colors and then reproduce all colors by intermixing them. We can come close but no cigar. If you think about it, you will realize that the objects we image have color and texture; we try to replicate the colors, but the texture is a different matter.

The facts are: Photo scientists emphasize what are called memory colors. These are skin tones and a variety of hues found in nature. One of the hardest jobs in commercial photography is to reproduce an artist’s painting. Try as we might, it takes the greatest of skills on the part of the photographer, combined with the greatest skills of the printer making the displayed image. No matter, the artist is always disappointed.

You have tasked yourself to make of faithful image of fabrics what have a specific color and texture. You will never be able to make a perfect match. All we can do is make a facsimile that comes close --  again no cigar!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Adobe DNG Profile Editor to change the camera profile. You can shift the green without changing any of the other colors.